# Prompt to enter (custom) document property in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, automation, field-codes

I created a template with a custom document property called "*myproperty*". I can access this using fields with the DOCPROPERTY "myproperty" command.
I want to make Word prompt the user for a value and set it as a value for *myproperty*. I know I can prompt using the FILLIN command, but I don't know how to pass the value to *myproperty*. The SET command seems to work only with bookmarks.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Regards,
naroslife

Comment: Only a small number of *built-in* properties can have their values set using field codes. For user-defined Custom properties, you have to use VBA (or whatever), or get the user to use the Custom properties dialog box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to achieve my goal using this skeleton code:

```
Private Sub Document_New()
Dim strValue As String
strValue = InputBox("Enter a value for 'myproperty':", "myproperty", " ")

' the value will be an empty string, "", if the user cancels
' or deletes the default space; fix that
If strValue = "" Then strValue = " "

ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("myproperty").Value = strValue

ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
End Sub
```